# Foreach loop over a list Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a list in scala that looks like the following:

```
val totalQuote: List[List[String]] = List(List("a","b","c"),List("1","2","3"),List("d","e","f"),List("4","5","6"))
```

I want to print out every element in the list using a foreach loop.  However when I run this:

```
totalQuote.foreach{ e =>
      val(a,b) = e
      println(a)
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(17, 10) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: List[String]
      val(a,b) = e
```

Not sure how to resolve this!

Answer (score 3):

You could use nested `for`-loops:

```
for {
  list <- totalQuote
  character <- list
} println(character)
```

Without `for`, this could also be written as:

```
totalQuote.foreach { list =>
  list foreach println
}
```

or even

```
totalQuote foreach (_ foreach println)
```

If you want to take only the first two elements out of every list, you could combine `for` with pattern-matching as follows:

```
for (a :: b :: _ <- totalQuote) { 
  println(a)
  println(b) 
}
```

or

```
for (a :: b :: _ <- totalQuote; x <- List(a, b)) println(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `e` is `List[String]` but

```
val (a,b) = e
```

only works if `e` is a tuple. Try this

```
val a::b::_ = e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following to print each element of the list

```
  totalQuote.flatten.foreach{x => println(x)}
```